# Concatenating pandas DataFrames with datetime columns

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate two DataFrames (called firstData and lastData) created from SQL queries.  However, when I try to concatenate them, I get an error that says `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int`.  Judging by this message, I'm thinking the issue is the concatenation with the AUTHORIZED field. Dummy data with what the data frame looks like is below. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

```
print firstData
  ORDER_ID    EMAIL             IP       AUTHORIZED  
0   1234567   dummy@dummy.net   x.x.x.x  2008-11-15 19:16:07   
1   8911234   dummy@dummy.com   x.x.x.x  2008-11-15 17:59:55   
2   4567833   dummy@dummy.com   x.x.x.x  2008-11-15 17:50:20   

     HOUR  DAY_OF_WEEK SHIPMENT_TYPE  ZIPS_MATCH     MERCH_SUBCAT     
0    19    7           Standard       1              Her Accessory      
1    17    7           Standard       1              Her Accessory      
2    17    7           Standard       1              Kid toy/clothes

print lastData   
  ORDER_ID  EMAIL              IP     AUTHORIZED 
3   1234567 dummy@dummy.net  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15 17:43:13 
4   8901234 dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15 13:18:01    
5   4567890 dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15 09:29:10   

   HOUR DAY_OF_WEEK  SHIPMENT_TYPE      ZIPS_MATCH    MERCH_SUBCAT
3  17    7           Standard           1             Bag   
4  13    7           Standard           1             Paperweight/boxes     
5  09    7           Standard           0             Candle   


concat(firstData, lastData)
   TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `list`, `dict`, `tuple`, or generator of `DataFrame` or `Series` objects to `concat`. What you're doing now will throw a `TypeError` because `lastData` is being passed as the `axis` argument (and there are numerous lines like `axis == 0`, which will trigger a `TypeError`). Do it like this:

```
In [31]: a
Out[31]:
   0        1                2        3           4         5
0  0  1234567  dummy@dummy.net  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  19:16:07
1  1  8911234  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:59:55
2  2  4567833  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:50:20

In [32]: b
Out[32]:
   0        1                2        3           4         5
0  3  1234567  dummy@dummy.net  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:43:13
1  4  8901234  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  13:18:01
2  5  4567890  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  09:29:10

In [33]: concat([a, b])
Out[33]:
   0        1                2        3           4         5
0  0  1234567  dummy@dummy.net  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  19:16:07
1  1  8911234  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:59:55
2  2  4567833  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:50:20
0  3  1234567  dummy@dummy.net  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:43:13
1  4  8901234  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  13:18:01
2  5  4567890  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  09:29:10

In [34]: concat([a, b], axis=1)
Out[34]:
   0        1                2        3           4         5  0        1  \
0  0  1234567  dummy@dummy.net  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  19:16:07  3  1234567
1  1  8911234  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:59:55  4  8901234
2  2  4567833  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:50:20  5  4567890

                 2        3           4         5
0  dummy@dummy.net  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  17:43:13
1  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  13:18:01
2  dummy@dummy.com  x.x.x.x  2008-11-15  09:29:10
```

This now raises an `AssertionError`, since commit `36142334` (which is in the v0.12.0 release) so you won't get this cryptic error anymore.